# API integration with Rails or Other Language

Tags: java, php, ruby

I need the API integration for the following site

1] alamo car service

2] avis car service

3] thrifty car service

4] hertz car service

If any one know anything regarding any of the above please reply.

Regards,

Salil

Comment: There's not much anyone can do with this question unless you tell us 1) what your goals are, 2) what you've planned so far to reach those goals, and 3) what you've learned so far about these services. And if you don't have answers to those, you'd best be doing some investigation yourself rather than asking around here.

Comment: I want to search things from different sites and i think it might work using the Curl. I would like to know how Curl works with Rails? Any example of it?

Comment: Just use curb in your controllers. How familiar are you with Rails (or MVC)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try curb (http://curb.rubyforge.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to visit/contact those companies sites directly and see if they have an API available for use. Probably much quicker and more finite.

Comment: I want to search things from different sites and i think it might work using the Curl. I would like to know how Curl works with Rails? Any example of it?